# Select data from 2 tables in mySQL, join it

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, json

I need to select data from 2 tables in my DB - comments and users. This is the structure of these tables:

**comments**:

commentID | commentDateAndTime | imageID | userID | comment

**users**:

userID | username

I need to select all the data in both tables, join it on userID, where imageID should be equal to `$imageID`. I tried the following `SELECT` statement:

```
    return json_encode(select("
    SELECT
     commentDateAndTime,
     imageID,
     userID,
     COMMENT,
     username
   FROM users
    JOIN comments
    ON comments.userID = users.userID
   WHERE comments.imageID = $imageID
   GROUP BY comments.comment   
"));
```

But I didn't receive any data.

Any advice, please?

Comment: Why do you need the group by? doesn't look like you're using it.

Comment: Try remove  GROUP BY comments.comment

Comment: @diEcho Yup, that worked. I also changed `SELECT commentDateAndTime, imageID, userID, comment, username` to `SELECT *` Now worked fine! Thank you!

Comment: @AlexAckerman: Throw that in an answer so that lgal can close this question out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using group by if you need all the result.

```
SELECT users.* , comments.*
FROM users JOIN comments ON comments.userID = users.userID 
WHERE comments.imageID = $imageID
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does auto-joins (from [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html): *"The FROM [...] clause indicates the table or tables from which to retrieve rows. If you name more than one table, you are performing a join"*).

Also, since there are two `userID` columns you need to be specific of which one by preceding the table name.

So your query could be like this:

```
SELECT commentDateAndTime, imageID, users.userID AS userID, comment, username
FROM comments, users
WHERE comments.userID = users.userID AND comments.imageID = $imageID
```